# how do i print receipt(which is activity layout) from my android app

Tags: android

I have to print some receipt using my own android application. Is it possible in android? Do I have to use third party API's? I am asking the question just because there is no proper solution,or documentation for print.

If there is some documentation or any solution, please provide me link. I need to know about the possibilities of printing document and receipt in android. I also want to know which printer would be the best?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ..you can print document use Bluetooth printer..I think following link will helpful to move your project next level.
[Best Printer for Android Mobile](https://youtu.be/9SUZRB0oL_M)